# vector of arrays error in adjacency matrix for graph implementation

Tags: c++, arrays, function, vector, declaration

I am going through this code

```
using namespace std; 


// A utility function to add an edge in an 
// undirected graph. 
void addEdge(vector<int> adj[], int u, int v) 
{ 
    adj[u].push_back(v); 
    adj[v].push_back(u); 
} 

// A utility function to print the adjacency list 
// representation of graph 
void printGraph(vector<int> adj[], int V) 
{ 
    for (int v = 0; v < V; ++v) 
    { 
        cout << "\n Adjacency list of vertex "
             << v << "\n head "; 
        for (auto x : adj[v]) 
           cout << "-> " << x; 
        printf("\n"); 
    } 
} 

// Driver code 
int main() 
{ 
    int V = 5; 
    vector<int> adj[V]; 
    addEdge(adj, 0, 1); 
    addEdge(adj, 0, 4); 
    addEdge(adj, 1, 2); 
    addEdge(adj, 1, 3); 
    addEdge(adj, 1, 4); 
    addEdge(adj, 2, 3); 
    addEdge(adj, 3, 4); 
    printGraph(adj, V); 
    return 0; 
}
```

This code should print the connections between the nodes in the adjacency matrix , which it does. However, i have a few doubts/questions.

1. In the add edge function , the vector of arrays is passed by value. I feel this is incorrect and should be passed by reference. Unless i am missing a trick here.

   void addEdge(vector adj[], int u, int v)
2. So i tried to convert the above to a reference function as follows

   void addEdge(vector (&adj)[], int u, int v)

But this ofcourse fails with the error :

> candidate function not viable: no known conversion from 'vector
>   [V]' to 'vector (&)[]' for 1st argument void addEdge(vector
>   (&adj)[], int u, int v)

I know there are different ways to represent the adjacency matrix,i.e array, vector of vectors, but i would really appreciate if some one can help me figure out this syntax.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For starters this code snippet

```
int V = 5; 
vector<int> adj[V];
```

is not a standard feature of the C++ Standard. C++ does not support variable length arrays.

You could write instead

```
const int V = 5; 
vector<int> adj[V];
```

When you are passing an array by value the expression specifying the array is implicitly converted to pointer to the first element of the array. So in fact each element of the array is passed indirectly using the pointer. The function does not create a copy of the array itself. It creates a copy of the passed pointer to the first element of the array.

On the other hand, a function parameter declared as an array is implicitly adjusted by the compiler to pointer to array element type.

So for example these function declarations

```
void f( int a[10] );
void f( int a[] );
void f( int *a );
```

declare the same one function and can be all included in a program though they will be redundant.

As for this declaration

```
void addEdge(vector (&adj)[], int u, int v);
```

then you did not specify the size of the array. So the first parameter has incomplete type.

Comment: Cheers. to clarify a call like addEdge(adj,0,1) will actually pass the pointer to the underlying vector of arrays ?

Comment: @RickoM The argument is implicitly converted to pointer to first element of the array. So in fact each element of the array is passed indirectly through the pointer. Using the pointer (for example in the subscript operator) you can change every original element of the array.

Answer (score 3):

You're getting confused about the relationship between arrays and pointers. First point, this

```
void addEdge(vector<int> adj[], int u, int v)
```

is completely and totally equivalent to this

```
void addEdge(vector<int>* adj, int u, int v)
```

The `[]` syntax was added to the C language specifically to confuse newbies (I can't think of any other reason). When you use `[]` in a function parameter you are really declaring a pointer.

So that is the second point, it's not possible in C or C++ to pass an array by value. So your concerns are misplaced. You are actually passing a pointer to the first element of your array, which is perfectly efficient.

My advice would be to change all the instances of `[]` in function parameters to `*`, so you aren't confused.